# Model accuracy score and prediction do not tally

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, logistic-regression

A very simple scikit-learn logistic regression model was created for a binary classification task.

Train and test set was split.

Random forest model and decision tree using the same data set gives about 0.9 accuracy.

Here is the logistic regression model:

```
logreg_model = LogisticRegression(random_state=99).fit(X_train, y_train)
logreg_acc = logreg_model.score(X_test, y_test)
logreg_pred = logreg_model.predict(X_test) 
print("Log reg model accuracy:", logreg_acc)
print("Log reg prediction:", logreg_pred)
print("Actual:",y_test)
```

Here are the results:

```
Log reg model accuracy: 0.8701298701298701
Log reg prediction: [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0]
Actual: [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

How can the accuracy be 0.87 while the prediction got all of the classifications wrong?
What are the bugs here?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### About the accuracy you have

You have most of the zeros predicted correctly. To me, the accuracy score you got looks reasonably right.

You can double check by using [accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html) on your `logreg_pred` and `y_test`.

#### About what you may be looking for

It seems you are more interested in whether you predicted your `1` correctly.

You may be interested in looking at other measures like [recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html), or [precision](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html).

Comment: ah yes, I am interested in the 1s, and yes recall and precision should be the better measure ! thank you.